# How to not generate ERRORLEVEL 1 on findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

I'm building a validation for my jobs on Jenkins to see if today is a holiday. I have a .csv file with the dates that is holiday, I just need to see if today is on this file.

For this in CentoOs I use the following code that works great:

```
    TODAY="`date +%d/%m/%Y`"
if  grep -qF $TODAY /home/holiday.csv; then   
    echo "ITS HOLIDAY, DONT RUN NOTHING"
    exit 0
else
    echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!"
fi
```

But for the Jobs that run on Windows I was searching for a equivalent of "grep" and found "findstr". Works pretty similar, but there is a problem, I just found validations with "ERRORLEVEL 1". My code is:

```
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x

set TODAY=%MyDate:~6,2%/%MyDate:~4,2%/%MyDate:~0,4%

findstr %TODAY% C:\holiday.csv

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!") ELSE (echo "ITS HOLIDAY, DONT RUN NOTHING")
```

The problem is, for Jenkins if the code returns ERRORLEVEL 1, the code has a error and Jenkins flag the execution with error, but in this situation there is no problem, because "not found == not holiday" (sure, for findstr is a error, but you guys get it).

Other problem is, I found that I just can put a "exit 0" and the job will not flag as a error, but if I do this the thing that will be on ' echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!" ' we will never know if has error or not (I can see on jenkins log, but its more intuitive if the execution show the correct result".

So, what can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand why you think that jenkins is choking on the errorlevel from the `findstr` command. The last command run is either `echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!"`, or `echo "ITS HOLIDAY, DONT RUN NOTHING"`. Neither of those should raise an error, so that last command will reset the errorlevel to `0`.

Comment: @Compo `echo` doesn't change the value of `%errorlevel%` though, so if it's still set to 1 from `findstr` not finding today in the list of holidays, I'd expect it to still be 1 after the echo.

Comment: Sorry, @SomethingDark, I perhaps shouldn't have been so cryptic, with my comment, what I should have said was that there is absolutely no reason why the parenthesized block, `(echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!")` cannot include a reset mechanism, so that the error level is always `0`. For example `(echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!" & Ver 1>NUL)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect OP has oversimplified the situation, and the actual code is

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!"
                 ask_mr_jenkins_something
                ) ELSE (echo "ITS HOLIDAY, DONT RUN NOTHING")
```

`echo` does not clear `errorlevel`, hence Jenkins sees `errorlevel`=1 when it starts.

To force `errorlevel` to 0, try

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo "ITS NOT HOLIDAY, RUN SOMETHING!"
                 ver>nul
                 ask_mr_jenkins_something
                ) ELSE (echo "ITS HOLIDAY, DONT RUN NOTHING")
```

`ver` reports the version number (no doubt you don't want to see that, hence `>nul` to suppress the report) and sets `errorlevel` to 0.

Comment: Alright! That's it. I tried running a python script with a expected error, jenkins returned error, then fixed the error, and jenkins reported success!
I will put my real code and make some tests, but probably thats exactly what I wanted. 
Really thanks dear @Magoo!